# C2676 binary '++': 'NumSet' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Tags: c++, overriding

I'm trying to override the ++ operation in C++, but I'm getting error C2676 on my usage of ++ on my class.

The way I overrode the command:

```
void NumSet::operator++() {

int newVal;

for (int i = 0; i < this->_filledCells; i++)
{
    newVal = this->_nums[i] + 1;

    if (this->isValid(this->_nums[i] + 1))
    {
        this->_nums[i] = newVal;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Number " << newVal << " isn't valid" << endl;
    }
}
}
```

The place I used the command, that is giving me the error:

```
NumSet* mySet = new NumSet();
mySet->insert(1);
mySet->insert(3);
mySet->insert(5);
mySet->insert(5);
mySet->insert(8);

// Check operator ++ - Increase each cell value by one.
(*mySet)++;
cout << *mySet << endl;
```

I overrode a number of operators, the only ones giving me errors (at least for now) are '++' and '--' which I wrote almost identically. I can't figure out what I did wrong here.

Comment: Take care about the different styles for pre- and postfix increment operator overloading. `(*mySet)++;` want's the postfix overload.

Comment: NumSet& NumSet::operator++() { /* code */ return *this; }